# iOS video player scrubbing image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I would like to implement preview image like youtube when user scrub the progress slider on iOS player. But I have no idea on how to kick start. Could anyone please show me the way or any hint? The app is playing m3u8 playlist. I have tried [AVAssetImageGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetImageGenerator_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAssetImageGenerator) but failed. It seems can't retrieve images from stream video type.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those small preview images are known as "BIF" - base index files - and they are pre-rendered rather than extracted from the live stream.

AFAIK the iOS SDK (AVPlayer etc) has no support for it but it wouldn't be hard to implement. First step is to generate the images. There's a guide to how to do this with Roku here: http://www.skoobalon.com/blog/2013/07/18/creating-roku-bif-files/

Comment: Thanks! It's really helpful.